# Is there an app-level entry and exit point I can use to keep track of the cumulative time my Android app has been running?

Tags: android

I have been tasked with keeping a cumulative record of exactly how long our Android app has been running on the device, this includes all time in the foreground **and** background.

I figured I would set a start-time in `SharedPreferences`, then do my calculations based off that. I thought that I would override the `onDestroy()` method and calculate the up-time and store that data in the `SharedPreferences` as well.

Then I remembered that we have several activities in our app and that if one activity's `onDestroy()` method were called, our other activities could still be running.

I set out to look for an app-level `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` I could use, but I haven't been successful; my first reaction would be to say "there isn't one".

So, is there an app-level entry and exit point I can use to keep track of the cumulative time our app has been running, foreground and background?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be surprised if this feature weren't built into Google Analytics already

Comment: This app is for our company only, it will never have contact with Google.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. What I would recommend is using a BaseAvtivity class and let all of your activities extend that class. That way the onDestroy of the Baseactivity is always called. Do your time management logic in the BaseActivity the way you described in your question. Another suggestion would be to uses your own Application class.

```
static class ActivityLifecycle implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    Activity currentActivity;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }
}
```

This way you can use the Application lifecycle methods to calculate the time spent in the app.

Comment: I had thought of using a `BaseActivity` but like I said, if activity #1 was destroyed, activity #2 or #3 might still be holding on, which would throw off my count.

Comment: You are free to use Application lifecycle methods to calculate the time spent in the application.

Comment: Which methods are these? I thought `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResumed()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onRestart()`, and `onDestroy()` were all on the activity only. Meaning that no one activity can tell me if the entire application is running or not.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle this might be helpful

Comment: Yes, right ... "activity". Nothing about the entire application itself.

Comment: https://www.klaasnotfound.com/2015/08/24/tracking-the-application-lifecycle-on-android/ I hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185372/discussion-between-android-muncher-and-brian).